# forEach loop in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular

I am working on a project with **Angular 2**.

In one of my scenario I get the Array from the API call.

Array is like : 
`[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}]`

Using this Array I want to create the table like
**key1**    **key2**     **key3**
value1  value2   value3
value1  value2   value3
value1  value2   value3

So, my question is how do I get the `key` and the `value` from the array
Is there any `forEach` loop?

Comment: Is your key1,key2, key3 static text (Never changes)? Or dynamic text (May change on data).

Comment: keys are dynamic @ParthaSarathiGhosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the data come from your API

You need to create a new KeysArray withe the following code snippet on your component. Assuming each object will hold same keys.

```
keysArray = Object.keys(this.apiData[0]);
```

Now iterate the keys array and apiData in your template as follows.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let key of keysArray; let i = index;">{{key}}</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of apiData;">
            <td *ngFor="let key of keysArray;">{{item[key]}}</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```